# To change background color of sharepoint 2010 template

Tags: sharepoint-2010

hiii everyone, i need help onto change the background color of the  template in sharepoint2010. i've placed the css in etc '
                     
           ul { background-color: rgb( 149, 206, 145); }

i've also try  but it doesnt work. help me please

Answer (score 0):

**ul** tag is probably not what you are looking for, you should look for the **body** tag instead.

My advice would be to create a custom master page using Sharepoint designer, from there you could include your own style and layout ...

if you use Sharepoint foundation [this](http://spfmasterpageselect.codeplex.com/) will let you select change the default master page.

Comment: This is correct. You should probably start by copying the master page that your site is already using (assuming you aren't going to be changing much else). From there, you just override the individual styles as needed. For instance on the v4 template the default background-color for the BODY tag is rgb(255,255,255). Just create a CSS file, add a BODY clause in there with your background-color, and add a ref to it in the master page. Make your newly created master page the default and you should be all set.